# styled-components local variable

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

**Coming from *SCSS* (*SASS*)**

What would be the appropriate *Styled-Components* implementation of the below *SCSS* code?

#### SCSS:

```
.circle{
  $size: 16px;  // <-- SCSS FTW. use such a trick in styled-components

  height: $size;
  width: $size;
  .. rest of properties...
}
```

#### Currently the *styled-component* (`Circle`) looks like this:

```
...lots of other styled exports

export const Circle = styled.div`
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
`

...lots of other styled exports
```

Problem is, I want to keep that "meaningless" `size` variable in the same context where it's consumed (just like in *SCSS*) because nothing else cares or will ever care about it. I don't think dumping a variable somewhere and then using it with `'${size}'` is a "clean" way. such tactics are petty and promote messy code-base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I have devised a neat trick to encapsulate variables only for a specific scope:

```
styled.h1(({size='4em', color='lime'}) => `
  font-size: ${size};
  color: ${color};
  text-align: center;
`)
```

---

I've written a [Medium post](https://medium.com/@yairevenor/styled-components-ultimate-props-local-theme-global-theme-combined-21f4d57c2e2b) in the past which breaks down the explenation of this method

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to create a separate file with all the variables that you want to use later in your style files:

```
export const Variables = {
  size: '16px',
  bgColor: 'red',
}
```

then you can import it:

```
import { Variables } from './Variables'

export const Circle = styled.div`
  height: ${Variables.size};
  width: ${Variables.size};
  background: ${Variables.bgColor};
  border-radius: 50%;
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use classic css properties (with IE11 polyfill in mind) like this:

```css
--radioWidth: 42px;  

  .MuiRadio-root {
    width: var(--radioWidth);
  }
  .conditionCollapse {
    padding-left: var(--radioWidth);
  }
```

Comment: how can there possibly be a polyfill for CSS properties... and what is "classic" about it? it's a relatively new thing from recent years.. a polyfill would have to constantly listen to all DOM changes that might affect the variables..it's insane

Comment: Only IE 11 but it works flawesly, you can read more about it on their github
https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties